# Making own virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, virtual-keyboard

I want to make my own virtual keyboard using JavaScript.

Please tell me the syntax how to add characters to a TextBox. Adding the first character is easy but adding the second one I am unable to do.

Anybody please give a hint/logic to add text to textbox on `keypress`.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Teneff said is the beginning.. this following code will be a hint for you..

```
<form name="virtual">
<input type="text" name="text"/>
<input type="button" onclick="a()" value="a" style="border:none;"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function a(){
    document.forms["virtual"]["text"].value += "a";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that when you press a key on a keyboard the cursor is not always at the end of the text

Answer (score 3):

**1:** Get all fields that will be able to write inside using the virtual keyboard

**2:** Attach an `onfocus` event to each field to know which was the selected field

**3:** After pressing the key on the keyboard add the letter to the value and return the focus to the field

[THIS is a simple example I've wrote](http://jsfiddle.net/VaKUv/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the character is being overwritten, make sure you're adding the next character to the textbox rather than simply overwriting it. Ie if your textbox contained "a"

```
textbox.value += 'b'; // would result in "ab"
textbox.value = 'b'; // would result in "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's this if you want to make it better I didn't make it fully just stole code ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Text</title>


<style media="screen">
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#keyboard {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #009;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #999;
}
#keyboard div {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
#space {
    width: 184px;
}
#keyboard label {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#keyboard input {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #666;
}
#keyboard input[type="text"] {
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#keyboard #back {
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 

#keyboard-placement {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 39%;
}
</style>
<div id="keyboard-placement">
<script>
(function() {
   'use strict';
   var i,c;
function init(){ 
/* get all the input elements within the div whose id is "keyboard */
   i=document.getElementById('keyboard').getElementsByTagName('input'); 
/* loop through all the elements */   

for(c=0;c<i.length;c++) {
/* find all the the input type="button" elements */
if(i[c].type==='button') { 
 /* add an onclick handler to each of them  and set the function to call */
   i[c].addEventListener('onclick',makeClickHandler(c));
   }
  }

/* this is the type="reset" input */
document.getElementById('clear').onclick=function() {
/* remove all the characters from the input type="text" element */
   document.getElementById('text').value='';
  }
 }

function makeClickHandler(c) {
   i[c].onclick=function() {
/* find the non-text button  which has an id */
if(i[c].id==='back') {
/* remove last character from the input the type="text" element using regular expression */
   document.getElementById('text').value=
   document.getElementById('text').value.replace(/.$/,'');
 }
/* find the text buttons */
else {
/* add characters to the input type="text" element */
   document.getElementById('text').value+=this.value.toLowerCase();
   }
  };
 }

   window.addEventListener?
   window.addEventListener('load',init,false):
   window.attachEvent('onload',init);
})();
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="keyboard" >

<div>
 <input type="button" value="Q">
 <input type="button" value="W">
 <input type="button" value="E">
 <input type="button" value="R">
 <input type="button" value="T">
 <input type="button" value="Y">
 <input type="button" value="U">
 <input type="button" value="I">
 <input type="button" value="O">
 <input type="button" value="P">
</div><div>
 <input type="button" value="A">
 <input type="button" value="S">
 <input type="button" value="D">
 <input type="button" value="F">
 <input type="button" value="G">
 <input type="button" value="H">
 <input type="button" value="J">
 <input type="button" value="K">
 <input type="button" value="L">
</div><div>
 <input type="button" value="Z">
 <input type="button" value="X">
 <input type="button" value="C">
 <input type="button" value="V">
 <input type="button" value="B">
 <input type="button" value="N">
 <input type="button" value="M">
</div><div>
 <input id="back" type="button" value="&#8592;">
 <input id="space" type="button" value=" ">
 <input id="clear" type="reset" value="clear">
</div><div>
<label>Track Search</label> - <input id="text" type="text" readonly="readonly">
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```